# How to specify `random:true` through karma-jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm having difficulty figuring out how/where to specify config data for Jasmine runs (which normally goes in a config file specified in Jasmine settings or through the loaded library). Specifically, I'm looking to set random:true through jasmine or karma-jasmine config.

[Here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/node.html) the docs specify where you can add it in a config file, but I have not been able to integrate the two configuations (or tell jasmine as run through karma where to find a config file).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass it through as `client.jasmine` in the configuration. The [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine#configuration) docs say like so:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: true
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I have successfully used this via [grunt-karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma) v2.0.0 with karma-jasmine v1.1.0. Annoyingly for me, grunt-karma isn't outputting the seed used each time, but I can see that the specs are randomised.

Comment: What is the usefullness of executing the test randomly? :)

Comment: @Nicolas It helps find tests that rely on sequential execution, for example using global variables where one test ends up relying on the value set by the previous test. They can be a problem if they are passing when they should fail if run on their own: false-positive =)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henry :)

Comment: not working when I tried to set it in my angular 10 project